Sanity Configuration must contain `projectId`
This is the error:
Configuration must contain `projectId`
    at initConfig (http://localhost:3001/static/js/bundle.js:65087:53)
    at _SanityClient2.config (http://localhost:3001/static/js/bundle.js:65901:101)
    at new _SanityClient2 (http://localhost:3001/static/js/bundle.js:65888:299)
    at createClient (http://localhost:3001/static/js/bundle.js:66026:29)
    at http://localhost:3001/static/js/bundle.js:66036:36
    at ./src/components/sections/featured/featured.jsx (http://localhost:3001/static/js/bundle.js:1328:75)
    at options.factory (http://localhost:3001/static/js/bundle.js:160931:31)
    at __webpack_require__ (http://localhost:3001/static/js/bundle.js:160330:32)
    at fn (http://localhost:3001/static/js/bundle.js:160589:21)
    at ./src/pages/home/home.jsx (http://localhost:3001/static/js/bundle.js:2657:96)

This is my client.js
import sanityClient from "@sanity/client";

export default sanityClient({
    projectId: 'twxbdh4g',
    dataset: "production",
    token: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SANITY_TOKEN,
    apiVersion: '2024-04-25',
    useCdn: true,
})

I've looked everywhere but I can't find a solution, this error popped up when I added a new sanity content block.
CORS Origins are added and credentials allowed.

I took a quick look at the documentation.
You are using the default import: import sanityClient from "@sanity/client";
Which is marked as depreciated:
/**

@public
@deprecated Use the named export createClient instead of the default export

*/
So you should use import {createClient} from '@sanity/client';
Relevant docs: https://github.com/sanity-io/client?tab=readme-ov-file#the-default-export-is-replaced-with-the-named-export-createclient
